# Transition doesn't work on hover off

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have problem. I wanted to transform div's background when hovering on, it works fine except when i put mouse off the div, the transition doesn't work then. How can i fix this?

When i put mouse off, it instantly changes to original flag.

```
$("#flag").hover(function(){
 $(this).css({
'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/EN.png")',
'background-size':'cover',
'transition':'1 s'
 });
}, function(){
$(this).css({
'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/PL.png")',
'background-size':'cover',
'transition':'1 s'
});
})
```

Comment: I just discovered, that the second transition works, when the first one is finished. Any way to work it around?

Comment: Can u add html code and make a snippet please

Comment: Not really, everything is ran on wordpress :(

Comment: Check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

try using jQuery `stop()` like so:

`$("#flag").hover(function(){
     $(this).animate({
         'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/EN.png")',
         'background-size':'cover'
  }, 1000);
}, function(){
     $(this).stop(true,false).animate({
         'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/PL.png")',
         'background-size':'cover'
     }, 1000);
})`

this should interrupt the animation queue and reset it, ready for the next one.

Comment: `css()` does not add to queue stack. `stop()` will do nothing

Comment: edited to accommodate @charlietfl 's point. If this doesn't work then I've got nothin, sorry.

Comment: animate only works on numerical values that can be incremented in  steps

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost Ok, just change transition part `1 s` to `1s` . It is a syntax problem:

```js
$("#flag").hover(function(){
 $(this).css({
     'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/EN.png")',
     'background-size':'cover',
     'transition':'3s'
 })}, function(){
 $(this).css({
     'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/PL.png")',
     'background-size':'cover',
     'transition':'3s'
 })
})
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>DIV HOVER:</p>
<div id="flag"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when you hover on it, the transition starts, but when you get mouse off while it's still going on, the animation will stop and instantly change to another flag.

Comment: Do u want slowly transition flag when mouse off right?

Comment: I just want it to transition on hover and when mouse is taken off while first transition runs without the jump effect. That's the problem.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand you.

Comment: Take a look at your snippet, when you mouse over flag, it starts to change, but as it's changing and you take mouse off, it jumps to another background without transition.

Answer (score 0):

CSS transition cant be paused or stopped in the middle of a transition. If we reset the transition duration in the middle of a transition it just stop the last transition.

And `JQUERY` does not support background change with transition effect that much efficient like CSS does. `JQUERY` transition will be like `fadeOut->change background Image->fadeIn`. that wont be nice, right?

So alternatively you could queue those `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to trigger them one after another.

Note : Obviously it will trigger the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events lately (like once we `mouseover` and immediately `mouseout` then the `mouseout` will run only after finishing the `mouseover` event that is 1 second). But we don't have an alternative.

```js
var animating = false,
  funqueue = [];
$("#flag").hover(function() {
  funqueue.push(function() {
    //console.log("mouseover");
    $("#flag").css({
      'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/EN.png")',
      'background-size': 'cover',
      'transition': '1s'
    });
  });
  if (!animating) executeFunctionQueue();
}, function() {
  funqueue.push(function() {
    //console.log("mouseout");
    $("#flag").css({
      'background': 'url("http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/PL.png")',
      'background-size': 'cover',
      'transition': '1s'
    });
  });
  if (!animating) executeFunctionQueue();
});

function executeFunctionQueue() {
  var funct = funqueue.shift();
  if (funct) {
    animating = true;
    funct.call();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (funqueue.length == 0) animating = false;
      else
        executeFunctionQueue();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flag" style="height:300px; background:url('http://visionfi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/PL.png'); background-size:cover; transition:1s">
</div>
```